# Weird result by manipulating Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Wilson's Theorem says that a number $n$ is prime iff $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \space (mod \space n)$, right?

This would mean:

$\begin{align*}1\cdot 2\cdot 3\dots (n-1) \equiv -1 \space (mod \space n)\end{align*}$

Let us assume that $n > 2$ and is prime. This would mean $n - 1$ is even and equals $2m$ for some $m$. 
Therefore, the above is equivalent to.

$\begin{align*}1\cdot 2\cdot 3\dots m\cdot (m + 1) \dots (2m - 1) \cdot 2m \equiv -1 \space (mod \space 2m + 1)\end{align*}$ or,

$\begin{align*}1\cdot 2\cdot 3\dots m\cdot (-m) \dots (-2) \cdot (-1) \equiv -(1\cdot 2 \dots m)^2 \equiv -1 \space (mod \space 2m + 1)\end{align*}$

Multiplying both sides by $ -1$ and taking the square root gives us,

$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\dots m \equiv 1 \space (mod \space 2m + 1)$

or, $m! \equiv 1 \space (mod \space 2m + 1)$, which can be seen to be false by putting $m = 2$. How come?

Comment: You can't square root both sides. For example $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ but $2 \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: $x^2 = a^2$ doesn't imply that $x=a$, even for congruences.

Comment: Also, $1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \dots m\cdot (-m)\dots (-2)\cdot (-1) = (-1)^m(1\cdot 2\dots m)^2$, which is not necessarily the same as what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, $1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \dots m\cdot (-m)\dots (-2)\cdot (-1) = (-1)^m(1\cdot 2\dots m)^2$ not $-(1\cdot 2\dots m)^2$.

The other mistake you made was taking the square root. It is true that if $x \equiv a \pmod p$, then $x^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod p$; the converse however is not true. If $p$ is prime, all we can say is that $x \equiv \pm a \pmod p$. To see this, note that $x^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod p$ is equivalent to the statement $p \mid (x^2 - a^2)$. Now note that $x^2 - a^2 = (x - a)(x + a)$, and because $p$ is prime, it must divide one of the factors. That is $p \mid (x - a)$ or $p \mid (x + a)$, i.e. $x \equiv \pm a \pmod p$.